# Appending to Array in Deeply Nested Dictionary of Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, append

I am having the following problem in Swift.  First, I declare a data structure, like this:

```
var books = [String : Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Array<Dictionary<String, String>>>>>]()
```

I later initialize the var like this:

```
books = [
    "Fiction" : [
        "Genre Fiction" : [
            "Mystery" : [
                "Classics" : [
                    ["Title" : "Ten Little Indians",
                     "Author" : "Agatha Christie",
                     "read" : "no"],
                    ["Title" : "A Study in Scarlet",
                     "Author" : "Arthur Conan Doyle",
                     "read" : "no"],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Note that the compiler does not complain about it.  Later, I create a new dictionary which I would like to append to that innermost array, like this:

```
var bookDict = Dictionary<String, String>()
bookDict = ["title" : dict.valueForKey("title") as! String,
            "author": dict.valueForKey("author") as! String,
            "read"  : dict.valueForKey("read") as! String ]
books["category"]["genre"]["focus"]["set"].append(bookDict)
```

However, I get a compiler error that "Cannot invoke append with an argument list of type (Dictionary < String, String>)".  This is confusing to me because the books data structure is declared such that that innermost array is an array of Dictionary< String, String>.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear during compile time if the key is really present in the dictionary so dictionaries always return optional values. You have to check this optionals:

```
if let category = books["Fiction"] {
    if let genre = category["Genre Fiction"] {
        if let focus = genre["Mystery"] {
            if var set = focus["Classics"] {
                set.append(bookDict)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can do it also like this:

```
books["Fiction"]?["Genre Fiction"]?["Mystery"]?["Classics"]?.append(bookDict)
```

Comment: This gets me closer!  It no longer gives a compiler error, which is good.  I have modified the append call to pull the subscripted strings from another dictionary, like this:

Comment: bookage[dict.valueForKey("category") as! String]?[dict.valueForKey("genre") as! String]?[dict.valueForKey("focus") as! String]?[dict.valueForKey("set") as! String]?.append(bookDict)

Comment: So what is the problem now?

Comment: But when I later println() the dictionary all of the new entries are not there.  Is it not the case that when a dictionary key is not found, that it creates the key automatically?  Seems like it worked that way in Obj-C.

Comment: You have named the key "Fiction" not "category", "Genre Fiction" not "genre", etc... you are using the wrong keys according to the code you posted. Please post the full code.

Comment: hmmm...  but if I want to grow that data by adding new elements to the arrays, how would I do that?  For example, "Fiction" might end up being one of many possible keys for that highest level array of dictionaries.  "Non-Fiction" being another possible key, for example.

Comment: I think I understand your current problem. Calling bookage[dict.valueForKey("category") as! String]? returns nil, because there is no value stored for this key. Keys _are_ created if they are missing in Swift, but in this way:  bookage[dict.valueForKey("category") as! String] = "SomeValue" . You are _querying_, not setting.

Comment: That makes sense!  Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you should stop trying to put always all the code in one line. First split it up, then you would get more finer grained error messages from the compiler. Later on, when everything works as expected you can combine it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87054/discussion-between-darko-and-user1639164).

Comment: I continued the discussion in chat.  I figured out how to create all of those nested missing keys... thanks again.